# Running a javascript function on a <a href>

Tags: javascript, php

I was just wondering how to trigger a JavaScript function on a `<a>` like this:

```
$('a').click( function() { your_code_here; return false; } );
```

and then using this to run a JavaScript function that runs something like this:

```
$.post("queries.php")
```

that runs a PHP function that runs a SQL query like this:

```
public function GetResults()
{ 
    list($subjectID, $sectionID, $principleID) = explode('#', $_POST["comboboxselections"]);
    $box = ""; // placeholder for the html results to be returned to 
    $sql = "SELECT media_id,title,blurb 
            FROM media 
            WHERE subject_id = $subjectID AND section_id = $sectionID AND principle_id= $principleID AND verified = 1"; 
    try
    {
        return $this->getResultsAndGenerateHTML($sql, $this->conn);
    }catch(exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

    }
}
```

1. Would this be the best option to run a SQL query from a HTML `<a>` or is there a better way of doing this?
2. I already know about MySQLi and PDO this project is not going live so I do not need to worry about SQL injection.
3. It has to be done on a HTML `<a>`. I know I could use a button which would be easier, but with my specification, it uses a `<a>` .

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Are you asking if this is the best way to approach calling a function from clicking on an anchor?

Comment: You've answered you're own question, `your_code_here;`.

Comment: @CameronTinker nothing is wrong with my code i am purely asking is this the best approach for calling a function from an anchor

Comment: There are many approaches to calling a function from an anchor click and this one is a common approach. Personally, I use Knockout.js click binding with the data-bind HTML 5 attribute, but that's my preference. It's really up to your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

prevents the default action of clicking he link and allows us to do our stuff.

```
$("a").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

//Do ur stuff

});
```

Visit this link:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

They have beautifully explained its functionality with examples

Comment: so are you saying my process would be correct or have you chosen something different could you explain please?

Comment: Generally if u click a link, it will make u to follow some path which e.preventDefault() will prevent and u can call write other function which will do the needed task for u. For ex: 1) If u want to pass any query strings with a click of a link, you can do it by preventing the default action of the link

Comment: I was just wondering if I have more than one `<a>` on this page will this function be run for all the anchors or would it be best to put in the anchors id

Comment: If u just include $("a"), it will run for all the <a>, if u just need for any one anchor tag, use id of tht anchor tag

Comment: thank you that is perfect ill accept your answer because it is the most clear and you have cleared everything up for me

Answer (score 2):

This way you have written includes all of your a tag, and if you have hyperlink in your menus your menus will do thus function too,
at first give an id to your hyperlink

```
<a href="#" id="Something">Click On Me</a>
```

then use this in jquery:

```
$("#Something").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //write your function here
});
```

this prevents page changing and will do your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it from anything you want, but an anchor tag is preferred since if the user doesn't have JavaScript activated, you will have a fallback and can redirect the user to an other page. Just be sure to prevent the default behaviour.

`return false` is not recommended for for that since it also prevent the event from bubbling. You should use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: May the downvoter explain why this doesn't answer *"is this the best approach for calling a function from an anchor"*?

Comment: this is a good example and helps me i believe user2401175 has explained your suggestion a bit more clearly but this is a great help